# Monitor blacks out randomly

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have 3 monitors connected to a Dell Display Link device that has 2 HDMI and one Display Port connections.  The 3 monitors are almost identical : 24" Asus HDMI, only one having both HDMI and DP ports.  There is no external power supply with these monitors (just a cable that you plug directly from the monitor to the power outlet).  The Dell DisplayLink is hooked to mny computer (a Dell Laptop).

My monitor connected on the DP blacks out randomly (about 3-4 times a week) which is quite annoying. When it happens, I can unplug and replug the DP cable or change that monitor's resolution to bring it back.

I tried updating drivers (DisplayLink and graphic card) but no luck.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

EDIT:  It just happened again, I get a message "Display Port No Signal" on screen, and switching the input (DP to HDMI and back to DP) doesn't change anything.  However, turning the monitor OFF and ON again bring it back as well.

Comment: Have you tried switching the monitor to one of the other ports to see if the problem persists? That would eliminate the DP device as the source of the problem. If you plug it into a different port and the problem still persists with that monitor only, you've probably got an internal issue with the monitor. If still under warranty, the manufacturer should replace it. If not, you have to replace it yourself.

Comment: I will try this.  If it works, it will mean the DisplayLink is the problem, if not then it's the monitor.

Comment: Are those monitors sharing the same power circuit as your laptop?

Comment: They were plugged all on the same powerbar, but I recently moved things around, so now the laptop and the monitors are on different powerbars but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 seems to have fixed the problem.  This confirms that it is a software problem (not hardware) between Windows and the DisplayLink driver...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Nvidia graphics card, open the Nvidia control panel and click on "Adjust Desktop Color Settings."  If necessary, scroll down to section #3 and change the drop down box labeled "Content type reported to display" to "Desktop programs."  Then hit "apply."  The problem should go away because the display will no longer try to switch between programs. Before making the change, my display kept going black whenever I scrolled over a YouTube video that had been embedded in a Facebook post.  Changing the setting in the Nvidia control panel resolved the problem.